# Access value in result set row where the value comes from a MySQL function call

Tags: php, mysql

So as normal PHP query returns an array it's never been explained to me how you actually extract the value from the query's result set array when the column value is the return value of a MySQL function call.

```
$countThemes = Singlequery(
    'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM items WHERE type = :type',
    array(':type' => 'theme'),
    $conn
);
```

This is my query and it returns;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(1)] => 5
        )
)
```

I need the value `5`.  So far I've setup this below but I'm not sure what to call because I can't call a column name like a normal `Select *` query.

```
<?php foreach ($countThemes as $countTheme) : ?>
     <a href="#" class="btn view-all">View All <?= $countTheme['name']; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias for the return of the `COUNT` function:

```
$countThemes = Singlequery('SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_items FROM items WHERE type = :type',
                            array(':type' => 'theme'), $conn);
```

Then, your array should have the index `num_items` instead of `COUNT(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work :

```
echo $result[0]['COUNT(1)'];
```

However, using an alias in the SQL query - as suggested by nickb - is more elegant in my opinion.